# Facebook login in iOS (Swift 4) - Get permissions and store in Firebase

Tags: firebase, facebook-login, swift4, facebook-ios-sdk

I've found some good resources on Stackoverflow and youtube helping getting around the fact that the Facebook iOS SDK descriptions are not up to date. I've now successfully managed to create the Facebook login feature and a new user is registered in Firebase. However my current issue is two fold.

1) I understand that Firebase do NOT store the email of the user under Authentication if the user log in with Facebook. My question is - how to get the email from Facebook so that I can store it under the users profile, and how do I ensure that a user that has signed in / logged in with Facebook one day and by email another day are the same user?

2a) The .userFriends info is a list of friends that also use the app - I'm struggling to understand what info that Facebook provide and how I can use this to suggest other friends the user can follow in the app. 
I've read the [Facebook SDK info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_friends)! But can someone help translating this into what it means in terms of Swift 4...

2B) Not knowing the data structure - I'm thinking of storing .userFriends into a new node - but unsure if I should do it under the specific user profile, or denormalise it and put it under root with the user uid as the identifier... let me know your thoughts please..

**Working code - issue is with the commented section**

```
    @objc func loginButtonClicked() {
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile, .email, .userFriends], viewController: self) { loginResult in // request access to user's facebook details
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print(grantedPermissions)
                print(declinedPermissions)

                // Check permissions granted and declined add do action depending... eg. get name and surname for profile
//                if FacebookAccessToken.grantedPermissions =  {
//                    // TODO: publish content.
//                    }
//                    else {
//                        var loginManager = LoginManager()
//                        loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile], viewController: self) { loginResult in
//                            //TODO: process error or result.
//                        }
//                }



                FacebookAccessToken = accessToken
                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: (FacebookAccessToken?.authenticationToken)!)
                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) {( user, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
               let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

                // Navigates back
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
                print("Successfully logged in user with Facebook")
            }
        }
    }
}
```